# How to simplify variables naming in included jinja2 templates?

Tags: variables, jinja2, naming

I want to simplify variables naming in jinja2 templates.

When use "include" keyword all variables are in one scope.
How to set one variable name with a different values for each included template ?

```
main.j2:
{% include 'left.j2' %}
{% include 'right.j2' %}

left.j2:
good way: {{ title }}
bad way: {{ left_title }} 

right.j2:
good way: {{ title }}
bad way: {{ right_title }}
```

I tried to override class method jinja2/environment.py:Environment().getitem(obj, argument).
As incoming arguments I receive obj and argument, but cant determine from which template it comes to substitute proper value.

Comment: `tried to override class method` Can you add this code to the Question? Or a snippet of it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`with` statement](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#with-statement) to override variables in a context:

```
{% with title='New title for left.j2' %}
{% include 'left.j2' %}
{% endwith %}

{% with title='New title for right.j2' %}
{% include 'right.j2' %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: thanks Dauros.
it works and I will keep this in mind !
\n
But how to set inner this scope from pyton code for certain template before calling Template.render() ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You can render the two templates separately with the specific variables, then put the rendered strings into the common template.